# VueJS modules involved in browser auto reload

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I'm new to node and Vuejs.

Working on this framework, I find that the auto reload of the browser on editing a file is very efficient and interesting, it makes win a lot of time and manipulations.

To reproduce this behaviour outside of a Vuejs project, I am looking for which modules are involved in this process, could you help me please?

I have already searched and tried modules that made that, but each time it demands to modify a file to include code to make the module work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Webpack you can setup the hot module replacement, that will reload the browser automatically.

cf: https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/

There is other tools you can use like https://www.browsersync.io/ that can be used with Gulp or Grunt.

> I have already searched and tried modules that made that, but each time it demands to modify a file to include code to make the module work.

Yes this tools are not magical you need to configure it and it depend of your project configuration.

Answer (score 0):

OK, thank you I'm going to check Webpack.

Indeed, configuring is not a problem, but what is more is include code inside existing scripts to make the thin work.